# How do I print only some of the objects in my array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, arrayobject

I am doing my homework for my CSCI class and have gotten to a hurdle.

In our homework we created a Passengers class and then our Flight Code.

Our Flight is to read in the first 20 people from a text file and then assign those to a spot in our array object. After those 20 people have been entered, the rest of the passengers(21-55) are to be inserted by the user with a dialog box.

I have done all of this, but after this we need to print out everyone in our array depending on what Flight class they have i.e all people that are first class are printed, and then Business and then Economy. When I tried to print all my objects, only the people from my text file are printed, not everyone that was entered by the user.

**Here is my code**

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Flight_EdgarFlores
    { 
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
      {
        String fullName=null;
        String seatClass=null;
        String seatNumber=null;
        String ff_Number=null;
        String points=null;
        String line, word;
        int seat_Choice, again;

        Passengers[] Pass; 
    final int NUM_OF_PASSENGERS= 55;  //size of array
    Pass = new Passengers[NUM_OF_PASSENGERS];

    Scanner  lineScan;
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("PassengerList.txt"));

    int line_counter = 0;
    int word_counter = 0;

    while(fileScan.hasNext())
    {
      line = fileScan.nextLine(); 

      lineScan = new Scanner(line);   // Scans each line of the file
      lineScan.useDelimiter(", ");

      word_counter = 0;
      while(lineScan.hasNext())  // Reads each word in the line 
      {

        word = lineScan.next();
        switch (word_counter)
        {
          case 0:
            fullName = word;
            break;  
          case 1:
            seatClass = word;
            break;
          case 2:
            seatNumber = word;
            break;
          case 3:
            ff_Number = word;
            break;
          case 4:
            points = word; 
            break;
          }
        word_counter++;
      }  
      if(word_counter==3)
        Pass[line_counter] = new Passengers(fullName, seatClass, seatNumber);

      if(word_counter==5)
       Pass[line_counter] = new Passengers(fullName, seatClass, seatNumber, ff_Number, points);

        line_counter++;
    }
    int counter=20;
    do
    {
      String full_Name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Full Name: ");

      String[] seatClassChoice = new String[3];
      seatClassChoice[2] = "Economy Class";
      seatClassChoice[1] = "Business Class";
      seatClassChoice[0] = "First Class";

      int classChoice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choose Seat Class", "Seat Class Choice", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, seatClassChoice, seatClassChoice[0]); 
      if(classChoice==0)
      {
        String[] seatChoice = {"1A", "2A", "3A", "4A", "5A", "6A"};
        seat_Choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choose Seat ", "Seat Choice", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, seatChoice, seatChoice[0]); 
      }
      else if(classChoice==1)
      {
        String[] seatChoice = {"7A", "7B", "8A", "8B", "9A", "9B", "10A", "10B", "11A", "11B"};
        seat_Choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choose Seat ", "Seat Choice", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, seatChoice, seatChoice[0]);
      }
      else if(classChoice==2)
      {
        String[] seatChoice = {"12A", "12B", "12C", "13A", "13B", "13C", "14A", "14B", "14C", "15A", "15B", "15C", "16A", "16B", "16C", "17A", "17B", "17C", "18A", "18B", "18C", "19A", "19B", "19C", "20A", "20B", "20C", "21A", "21B", "21C", "22A", "22B", "22C", "23A", "23B", "23C", "24A", "24B", "24C" };
        seat_Choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choose Seat ", "Seat Choice", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, seatChoice, seatChoice[0]);
      }
      Pass[counter] = new Passengers(full_Name, seatClass, seatNumber);
      again = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Add another Passenger?");
      counter++;
    }while((counter<NUM_OF_PASSENGERS)&& (again==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION));

    Pass[0].addFrequentFlyer("#2AZ433", "4455"); //adds flyer number and flyer points to object at index 0

    for(int i=0; i<NUM_OF_PASSENGERS; i++)
    {
      if(Pass[i].getseatClass().equals("First Class"))
      System.out.println(Pass[i] + " , " + i);

    }
    for(int i=0; i<=NUM_OF_PASSENGERS; i++)
    {
      if(Pass[i].getseatClass().equals("Business Class"))
      System.out.println(Pass[i] + " , " + i);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<=NUM_OF_PASSENGERS; i++)
    {
      if(Pass[i].getseatClass().equals("Economy Class"))
      System.out.println(Pass[i] + " , " + i);
    }

    }
}
```

**Here is my Passengers Class**

```
public class Passengers
{
  private String fullName, seatClass, seatNumber, frequentFlyerNumber, flyerPoints;

  public Passengers (String full_name, String seat_class, String seat_number, String frequent_flyernumber, String flyer_points)
  {
    fullName=full_name;
    seatClass=seat_class;
    seatNumber=seat_number;
    frequentFlyerNumber=frequent_flyernumber;
    flyerPoints=flyer_points;
  }
  public Passengers (String full_name, String seat_class, String seat_number)
  {
    fullName=full_name;
    seatClass=seat_class;
    seatNumber=seat_number;
  }

  public void addFrequentFlyer (String frequent_flyer_number, String flyer_Points)
  {
    frequentFlyerNumber=frequent_flyer_number;
    flyerPoints=flyer_Points;
  }

 /* public String getLastName()
  {
    String lastName="";
    int nameLength= fullName.length();
    for(int i =nameLength; i> 0; i--)
    {
      if(full_name.charAt(i)!=' ')
        lastName+=fullName.charAt(i);
      else
        break;
    }
   }*/

  public String getseatClass()
  {
    return seatClass;
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    return fullName + ", "+ seatClass + ", " + seatNumber;
  }
}
```

Comment: Given this is a school assignment (thanks for being honest about that), I think it is important for your learning that you spell out what you have tried. In this case, there appears to be no evidence in your code that you have provided any attempt to load the additional passengers provided by the user. Please provide any attempts you have made to load those s customers, otherwise this just looks like you are asking someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: they create the Passenger each time in the while loop with the line Pass[counter] = new Passengers(full_Name, seatClass, seatNumber); @Alan ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your throwing an array out of bounds exception because you are doing the following check in your for loop for the Business and Economy passengers

```
for(int i=0; i<=NUM_OF_PASSENGERS; i++)...
```

However for your First Class passengers you do

```
for(int i=0; i<NUM_OF_PASSENGERS; i++)...
```

Since you are doing i <= NUM_OF_PASSENGERS, once i = NUM_OF_PASSENGERS you are going to attempt to access that index which doesn't exist because arrays are 0 based and the last index in your array is actually NUM_OF_PASSENGERS - 1, therefore when you attempt to print the Business or Economy passengers you run into an array out of bounds exception.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Flight_EdgarFlores.main(Flight_EdgarFlores.java:103)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)   **I get this error**